# 8086 masm, how to skip entering object filename, source listing, etc and to directly execute asm file in DOSBox using Notepad++

Tags: assembly, notepad++, masm, dosbox, nppexec

I am using DOSBox to run masm.exe.

When every time I compile and link my source file and object file, it is very annoying to keep pressing "Enter" key just to skip entering object filename, source listing, cross-reference, etc.

My friend once taught me how to skip these but I forgot after one semester and when I ask him, he also forgot too.

I am working on my assignment so if I can skip this, I can avoid wasting time to press hundred times of "Enter" key.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `masm /help`?

Comment: @Jester I tired but I didn't find option to hide or suppress them.

Comment: Then your masm must be different from mine which says: `masm /options source(.asm),[out(.obj)],[list(.lst)],[cref(.crf)][;]` meaning you can list the files on the command line and then it won't ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to [@Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester).

<s>Just add 4 commas behind your file name.</s>

Just add a semicolon behind your file name ~ [@Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826372/ross-ridge)

For example, you need to compile `foo.asm` and link `foo.obj`:

*File extension can skip.

```
masm foo;
```

Same for linking

```
link foo;
```

---

Usage:

So you can directly execute your asm file through Notepad++ using NppExec

```
"<insert your DOSBox directory>" -c "mount <insert drive that contain 8086 folder> <insert 8086 folder directory>" -c "<insert drive that contain 8086 folder>:" -c "masm $(NAME_PART);" -c "link $(NAME_PART);" -c "$(NAME_PART)"
```

For my script is:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74\DOSBox.exe" -c "mount d d:\8086" -c "d:" -c "masm $(NAME_PART);" -c "link $(NAME_PART);" -c "$(NAME_PART)"
```

This script helps you execute your .asm file only with one key press instead of 30+ key presses (yes, I counted).

---

The following steps is for people don't know how to use Notepad++ or NppExec:

1. Install Notepad++
2. Install Plugin Manager
3. Install NppExec using Plugin Manager
4. Press F6
5. Paste the script
6. Press save and give a name
7. Go to Plugins > NppExec > Advanced Option
8. Select the script you save in Associated script > Add/Modify > Close
9. Go to Macro > Modify Shortcut/Delete Shortcut > Select Plugin
   commands tab > Set a shortcut for your script

*Remember to put your `.asm` file in the same directory with your `masm.exe`

Done! Hope I minimize your misery.

Comment: On Linux (building native executables with NASM + `ld`), I typically use a script to assemble+link, then on the same line actually run the program if it assembled ok.  (`asm-link foo.asm && ./foo`).  So my workflow is: 1) save in emacs, 2) alt+tab 3) up-arrow + return.